# TextDecoder TextEncoder feature detection in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use TextDecoder TextEncoder API's on my website. How can I check if it is available.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=textencoder says IE and Edge still doesn't support it.

What is the best way to make sure these libraries exist on browser. Is there any drop in libraries that would pollyfill? **And if it does not exist can I conditionally load a pollyfill**. I do not want to load pollyfills if it is not necessary for that browser.

Comment: A shim allowing to use this interface in browsers that don't support it: https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding

Comment: @MajidFouladpour That's deprecated now, and archived!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `typeof` to check whether or not they are defined:

```
typeof(TextEncoder)!='undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to use the property of window instead of the variable. Otherwise the browser can give you an error: `'TextDecoder' is not defined`

```
if(window.TextDecoder === undefined){
   // load some pollyfill
}
```